# Does the waiver budget reset after a transaction?

Tags: yahoo-fantasy-sports

I'm trying to understand how [Free Agent Acquisition Budgets](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SLN6118) (FAABs or waiver budgets) work in Yahoo!'s fantasy basketball game.

We all have a $100 budget to spend bidding on players who are on the waiver wire.

If I bid $10 on a player my budget will then be $90. If I win the waiver claim, will my budget remain at $90 for the rest of the season?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiver budget does not reset.

In the example in the question the manager will only have $90 to work with for the rest of the season.